# Set Jenkins build status to Success if one of jobs fails

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

I have a pipeline build with next stages:

[image]

The result of job C may be unsuccessful, but it should not influence on status of the Build. This should be blue:

[image]

Is it possible to do this in pipeline plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **propagate: false**

Try the following code:

```
stage 'C'
build job: 'Job that fails', propagate: false
```

Comment: You did not say that you are calling another job there.. If not using the `build` step, then @Amityo's answer is AFAIk the only solution currently.

Answer (score 2):

Try/Catch on stage c will result in success if stage c fails

```
try {
    // stage c
} catch(e) {
}
```